# Hiding menu item crashes on Activity Start

Tags: android

I have followed some steps on hiding and showing menu items. But unfortunately my app crashes. What could I be doing wrong?

This is my Activity:

```
private MenuItem menuItem;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alcohol_type_page);

 invalidateOptionsMenu();
    menuItem.setVisible(false);
}

 //TOOLBAR SETTINGS
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu_icon, menu);

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.view_orders);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help! :D

Comment: post your stacktrace i guess it's null reference.

Comment: @IbrahimAli yes sir you are correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update

```
  private MenuItem menuItem;
  private boolean menuItemShow;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_alcohol_type_page);

  }

  //TOOLBAR SETTINGS
  @Override
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.activity_menu_icon, menu);

    menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.view_orders);
    menuItem.setVisible(menuItemShow);
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
  }
```

---

onCreateOptionsMenu is invoked after onCreate,you shouldn't set menu item visibility in onCreate method.

Comment: Yes sir, but I want to control hiding and showing of a menu item sir. When I hide the menuitem in the onCreate it crashes the app how would I do that?

Comment: you can have a field in the activity identify the visibility of the menuItem,and set visibility when menu item inited

Comment: i add the example,you can have a look

Comment: Thanks sir for all the help! I really appreciate it :D